# Mod_rewrite regex for url shortening service

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I recently made a small url shortener. Now i'm stuck at trying to figure out the regex for mod_rewrite. Here is what I have: (for lighttpd)

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "mywebsite.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/mywebsite.com"
    url.rewrite-once = ("^/create.php(.*)" => "/create.php$1",
                        "^/(.*)" => "/index.php?key=$1")
}
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, this is what I want it to do:

mydomain.com/blahblahblah -> mydomain.com/index.php?key=blahblahblah

UNLESS, it is mydomain.com/create.php, then I want regex to ignore it. How can I do this?

Comment: What output are you getting? I'm not familiar with the language you're using, but I'm going to throw an idea out there anyway. In the `("^/create.php(.*)" => "/create.php$1",  "^/(.*)" => "/index.php?key=$1")` part you're clearly generating a hash / dictionary / map / associative array / whatever it's called in this language. Does this language do ordered maps or unordered maps? If it's an unordered map then you can't control the order in which it tries the regexes. If it tries `"^/(.*)"` first, the other one will have no effect, and it will treat all URLs as if they weren't `create.php`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a conditional? [(docs)](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_Configuration), the `!~` is a negative regex compare.

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/create.php(.*)" {
    url.rewrite-once = ( "^/(.*)" => "/index.php?key=$1")
}
```

As it is now, the rewrite rule matching create.php is a NOP, it doesn't change the url at all.

You could also do `url.rewrite-once-if-not-file = ( "^/(.*)" => "/index.php?key=$1")`.

Edit: `url.rewrite-once-if-not-file` isn't valid, `url.rewrite-if-not-file` is, but does produce different behaviour than a rewrite with `once` would.